CHAR array to std::string
When the title is "Pesquisa de domínio GoDaddy - Brave"
    CHAR title[256];
    int r = GetWindowTextA(hwnd, title, 256); // r: 35
    std::string windowTitle(title);

    std::string str = "Pesquisa de domínio GoDaddy - Brave";
    auto s1 = QByteArray::fromStdString(windowTitle).toBase64();
    auto s2 = QByteArray::fromStdString(str).toBase64();

The conversion of the char array to std::string doesn't work properly there's an error on the: í.
What's the proper way to convert a CHAR array containing these kind of 'special' characters to a std::string without relying on using GetWindowTextW and/or a wstring?
Values seen on debugger (VS22):


What is the type of TCHAR for you.  Typically that is wchar_t, not char

@NathanOliver its CHAR not TCHAR, on Windows its typedef char CHAR;

Are you sure the error is on the conversion to std::string, and not in the code that tries to print the std::string? Use the debugger to inspect the contents of the std::string and see what happened to the í.

I see that, but per this, the type of the function parameter is LPTSTR which is a pointer to a TCHAR, which might be wchar_t.

What's the result code returned by GetWindowTextA? Could we hit you up for a [mre]?

@NathanOliver that page is inconsistent. In another place it shows the type of the function parameter as LPSTR. Given that it is an A function, LPTSTR doesn't make sense and is probably a copy and paste error in the docs. This being an encoding issue at some point along the line does.

What is windowTitle? Can you provide a [mre]?

You are going need to use std::wstring or std::basic_string<UTF8>.  Don't trust std::string for non-ASCII characters.

You could use encoding past the 0x7f ASCII value using Windows Code Page, but UTF-8 is much more reliable and easier to use.

@RaymondChen i added the values seen on debugger. -3CxEZiVlQ what do you mean what is windowTitle? its a std::string? -user4581301 the return is 35.

You can see in the debugger that character windowTitle[15] is í, as expected. Why do you think it is wrong?

Because the values doesnt match when i create it as std::string str = "Pesquisa de domínio GoDaddy - Brave"; as do the b64 codes.

That's because your str was encoded in Utf-8. Windows uses CP_ACP for 8-bit characters. Different encodings will use different representations. If you want utf-8, you will either have to convert from ACP to utf-8, or configure your ACP to be equal to utf-8.

The B64 byte strings are correct. The first decodes to a normal i, while the second is the UTF-8 encoded í. It is likely that whatever you are using to display the string is failing to accept a UTF-8 string.

"Configure your ACP to be equal to utf8" is this a project setting ? What are the cons of doing this? how is this called so i can search and learn more about?

@Laila see Use UTF-8 code pages in Windows apps on MSDN

You can change Windows locale to en_US.UTF-8

If you create a manifest and set the encoding to utf8:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <application>
    <windowsSettings>
      <activeCodePage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2019/WindowsSettings">UTF-8</activeCodePage>
    </windowsSettings>
  </application>
</assembly>

The result of both strings will match.

You should explain WHY this causes both strings to compare equal. Also note that this option only works in Windows 10 v1903 (May 2019 Update) and later

UTF-8 becomes the default for Windows API calls

There is no problem with the code you have shown. CHAR is just an alias for char, and std::string will happily consume any char[] array you pass in, it doesn't care how the contents of the char[] array are encoded just as long as it has a null character in it (which GetWindowTextA() does write out), since you are using the std::string constructor that expects a null-terminated string.
Whatever problem you are having with the í character is in a different area than what you have shown in your question.  GetWindowTextA() will output a char[] string that is encoded in the user's ANSI locale, so whatever is consuming the std::string afterwards will need to take that locale into account.

On a side note: GetWindowTextA() returns the number of chars it output, not including the null terminator.  You should pass that value to std::string constructor, eg:
CHAR title[256];
int len = GetWindowTextA(hwnd, title, 256);
std::string windowTitle(title, len);


UPDATE: in your screenshot, you have two std::string objects that are using different encodings, that is why they are not equal. windowTitle is ANSI encoded, whereas str is UTF-8 encoded. This is because windowsTitle is using the user's ANSI locale whereas str is assigned a string literal and your source file is encoded in UTF-8. í in the user's ANSI locale is char 0xED, whereas in UTF-8 it is chars 0xC3 0xAD, which displays as Ã- when  interpreted in a Latin language. That is what you are seeing.

The question got closed but i learned a lot from you guys, thank you!
